# HAST sync complete FreeBSD 10.2

Tags: freebsd, high-availability

The [handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/disks-hast.html) says:

> Check the status line in the output. If it says degraded, something is wrong with the configuration file. It should say complete on each node, meaning that the synchronization between the nodes has started. **The synchronization completes when hastctl status reports 0 bytes of dirty extents**. [emphasis added]

When googling it appears that earlier versions of `hastctl status` would give a lot of information including a "dirty" field. Eg:

```
role: primary
provname: mirror
localpath: /dev/da0s2
extentsize: 2097152
keepdirty: 64
remoteaddr: 192.168.0.2
replication: memsync
status: complete
dirty: 17142120448 bytes
```

However, when I type `hastctl status` I get:

```
myhast  complete primary        /dev/gpt/hast   192.168.1.2
```

So much less information. Adding multiple `-d` options doesn't seem to help.

When adding a secondary node in a FreeBSD HAST setup, how can I know when the synchronisation to the secondary has completed?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The information now seems to be available via `hastctl list`

```
myhast:
  role: primary
  provname: myhast
  localpath: /dev/gpt/hast
  extentsize: 2097152 (2.0MB)
  keepdirty: 64
  remoteaddr: 192.168.1.2
  replication: memsync
  status: complete
  workerpid: 1540
  dirty: 0 (0B)
  statistics:
    reads: 1216
    writes: 24814
    deletes: 0
    flushes: 0
    activemap updates: 736
    local errors: read: 0, write: 0, delete: 0, flush: 0
    queues: local: 0, send: 0, recv: 0, done: 0, idle: 255
```